# How do I set up Caching Service

Tags: server.app

I'm confused setting up OS X Server 5.2 to cache IOS and MacOS updates on our local network. The Server `Leo` seems to cache software for some devices but not others. `Leo` is connected to the internet via ethernet and to the local network via wi-fi as follows, so presumably I have to tell the Caching Service to allow particular networks ... but which ones?

Leo's network interfaces (per OS X Server Overview tab)

```
Ethernet: 81.137.126.xxx
Wi-Fi:    192.168.1.65
```

And this is what the router says:

```
  Leo-WiFi  192.168.1.65      
  iMac-WiFi 192.168.1.72 
  iPhone    192.168.1.74    
  iMac      192.168.1.69    
  Leo       81.137.126.xxx
```

(All the above connect to the internet via the router's ISP-allocated Public IP Address currently: 81.139.29.yyy)

Comment: [How to deploy and customize caching for your network](https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.2/#/apdC36C9994-1533-4DCB-9CFF-870CB0FADCDB)

Comment: @njboot If only life were that simple! Yes, of course I've read and re-read that page .... and after that I posted the question. It's not at all clear what "other networks" mean. Does Leo think they're some other networks that its not a part of? I guess I'm going to have to experiment .... and post back. I was hoping someone would have had a similar problem ... must be a very common setup.